# ItextSharp smooth background shade

Tags: itext, pdf-generation

I am working on pdf using iTextSharp and product owner decided to have a "stickers" alike text boxes casting a shadow on background for it. I was searching the Internet and couldn't find a hint to how to achieve this effect. The design provided for it is as follows:
[image]

Could anybody more experienced with iText or iTextsharp help me by advising on how to achieve such effect please?
Kind regards 
Karol

Comment: Does my answer help? Or are there still questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hints and links in Joris' answer, one can easily implement a helper method like this to draw the shaded rounded rectangles:

```
void DrawRoundedShadedRectangle(PdfWriter writer, float x, float y, float w, float h, float r, float shade, BaseColor innerColor, BaseColor shadeColor, BaseColor outerColor)
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x - shade, y + r, w + 2 * shade, h - 2*r);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingRight = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, x + w, y, x + w + shade, y, shadeColor, outerColor, false, false);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingRight);
    PdfShading shadingLeft = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, x, y, x - shade, y, shadeColor, outerColor, false, false);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingLeft);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x + r, y - shade, w - 2 * r, h + 2 * shade);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingTop = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, x, y + h, x, y + h + shade, shadeColor, outerColor, false, false);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingTop);
    PdfShading shadingBottom = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, x, y, x, y - shade, shadeColor, outerColor, false, false);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingBottom);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x + w - r, y + h - r, r + shade, r + shade);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingTopRight = PdfShading.SimpleRadial(writer, x + w - r, y + h - r, r, x + w - r, y + h - r, r + shade, shadeColor, outerColor);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingTopRight);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x - shade, y + h - r, r + shade, r + shade);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingTopLeft = PdfShading.SimpleRadial(writer, x + r, y + h - r, r, x + r, y + h - r, r + shade, shadeColor, outerColor);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingTopLeft);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x - shade, y - shade, r + shade, r + shade);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingBottomLeft = PdfShading.SimpleRadial(writer, x + r, y + r, r, x + r, y + r, r + shade, shadeColor, outerColor);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingBottomLeft);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.Rectangle(x + w - r, y - shade, r + shade, r + shade);
    canvas.Clip();
    canvas.NewPath();
    PdfShading shadingBottomRight = PdfShading.SimpleRadial(writer, x + w - r, y + r, r, x + w - r, y + r, r + shade, shadeColor, outerColor);
    canvas.PaintShading(shadingBottomRight);
    canvas.RestoreState();

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.SetColorFill(innerColor);
    canvas.SetColorStroke(innerColor);
    canvas.RoundRectangle(x, y, w, h, r);
    canvas.FillStroke();
    canvas.RestoreState();
}
```

For example,

```
DrawRoundedShadedRectangle(writer, 100, 500, 200, 100, 10, 20, BaseColor.GREEN, BaseColor.RED, BaseColor.WHITE);
```

draws this:

[image: Green-Red-White]

And this code

```
DrawRoundedShadedRectangle(writer, writer.PageSize.GetLeft(100), 300, writer.PageSize.Width - 200, 100, 10, 10, BaseColor.ORANGE, BaseColor.YELLOW, BaseColor.WHITE);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
canvas.SaveState();
canvas.Rectangle(writer.PageSize.Left, writer.PageSize.Bottom, writer.PageSize.Right, 300);
canvas.Clip();
canvas.NewPath();
DrawRoundedShadedRectangle(writer, writer.PageSize.GetLeft(100), 100, writer.PageSize.Width - 200, 200, 10, 10, BaseColor.WHITE, BaseColor.YELLOW, BaseColor.WHITE);
canvas.RestoreState();
```

draws this

[image: Orange/White - Yellow - White]

By tweaking the **r**adius, the **shade**, and all the color parameters this should become very similar to the provided design.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am about.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with iText.
It's a matter of using drawing operations on the canvas to achieve the effect.
in your case
 - a rounded rectangle, filled with orange
 - a rounded rectangle underneath it, filled with white

Comment: how would you achieve that smooth shading ?
please make note that it is kind of uniorm in every direction...

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/absolute-positioning-lines-and-shapes/itext7-how-add-shading-pattern-custom-shape